# How to export Catalog from Hybris through CronJob and export to External system via pagination?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm new to Hybris. Need to export full/delta Catalog data from Hybris and make a web service to an External system. Currently, I have created a new CronJob which runs every day to perform this action. Kindly let me know how can we achieve that.

I have referred various blogs but all are mentioning about FlexibleSearchQuery. Are there any out of the box methods to achieve that functionality.

Comment: Catalogs (product, cms, media, etc) have a lot of different types. Which types are you working on?

Comment: I need to pull the data for all the types of Catalogs.

Comment: I think this is not feasible. For example, medias (image/video/etc) saved as file on file system. You need custom development for some types. Generally you can find relational types with catalog using type system. Then create export impex for types and running them.

I think you miss something about issue, all of these huge data can be meaningful for external system. Please re-check your needs.

Answer (score 0):

hybris datahub has some sync functionality for SAP ERP. Maybe you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OCC `GET /{baseSiteId}/export/products` endpoint if your third party system can pull data from a REST service.

The endpoint produces all products, or all products changed since `timestamp`

The full documentation is available here:
https://help.hybris.com/1808/api/ycommercewebservices/index.html#_exportproductsusingget

Answer (score 0):

Speaking fundamentally from a good solution architecture perspective. I recommend to explore a option which does not require Hybris to actively send the data via service call to a third party system. Hybris should be concerned with the commerce. Unless you are also using it as a PIM.

Further you did not mention the protocol or type of payload the service expects. Anyways going with an assumption that you will deliver a zip file containing CSV/XML for products and product media all in one. Here is how I would do it.

1) Define a Job:
You can write a Cronjonb in Groovy on the fly (no deployment required) and or in Java in a standard way (require deployment).

2) Logic to fetch data and export
Use FlexibleQuery to fetch the products from the catalog version you need and then zip the batch into a zip file (e.g. mediaService.setStreamForMedia(media, new ByteArrayInputStream(products.toByteArray()), "mystore-mycatalog-export.zip", "application/zip")
. This will write the file to a zip and give you a URL that you can put into the Event which can trigger another cronjob to actually make the service call and send that file.

3) Write a cleanupjob to get rid of the already sent loads. Because of the size,  your disk will get filled rapidly to a point that your system will fail.